# com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify

Am trying to perform a query on my entities in my android project backend module but am getting a very weird error

```
Error loading User(123456789)/Message(101112134):
Cannot cast java.lang.Long to java.util.Date
```

**There is nowhere am casting a long to a Date in my entities or in my query**

**My query**

```
User user = ofy().load().key(userkey).safe();//This statement compiles successfully

    com.googlecode.objectify.cmd.Query<Message> query = ofy().load().type(Message.class);
    query = query.ancestor(user);
    query = query.filter("otherUser", withKey);

    QueryResultIterator<Message> iterator = query.iterator();
    int num = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     //.........
    }
```

The line that throws that error is `while (iterator.hasNext())`

Below is my Message Entity

```
@Entity
public class Message {
@Id
Long id;

@Parent
@Index
Ref<User> appUser;

@Index
Ref<User> otherUser;

 @Index
Date dateCreated;

String  message;

public Message() {
    dateCreated = new Date();
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

}
```

**my user entity**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
@Id
Long id;

@Parent
@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
private Key<User> parentKey;

String name;

public User() {

}

public void setAncestor(String groupid){

    parentKey = Key.create(User.class,groupid);
    dateCreated = new Date();
}
}
```

**Why** am i getting `Cannot cast java.lang.Long to java.util.Date` error?
`

Answer (score 0):

Sometime during the life of your application you saved an entity with a numeric `dateCreated` value. That data is in the datastore, now you're trying to load it as a `Date`. Objectify expects `Date` values for `Date` fields, thus the cast exception.

If you need to preserve this data, change the field to type Object and post-process it in an `@OnLoad` method. After you load/save your existing entities, you can change it back to `Date`. More help can be found here:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/SchemaMigration

Comment: am finding it difficult to find the error between this two entities. does it mean the problem is at entity user or Message or both? `User(123456789)/Message(101112134)`

Comment: This is most likely a key referencing a Message. Message keys include a `@Parent` User key, thus the composite.

Comment: i had to delete all message entities, rebuild my app, deploy my backend again and everything worked.